# Replacing desktop WPF Applications with HTML5

Tags: asp.net, wpf, html

Our little department has been working with WPF for a number of years now, there are only two of us, a designer and a programmer (me). We produce business applications for our company such as shipment tracking and the like.

We've recently began looking into a redesign of our company website and part of this has been a long running discussion on moving our desktop applications into web applications via the website, there are numerous reasons for this I wont go into.

Now the problem I'm having is actually wrapping my head around what HTML5 is and isn't I've spent long hours googling and finding mainly arguments for an against this and that, but i still lack a fundamental understanding of a few points, which I'm hoping to get cleared up.

### 1. Does HTML5 still *need* back-end code, such as PHP or ASP.NET?

This is a sticking point for me, our needs are pretty standard. We need to produce an application that can collect and display data from a database, it will need to do some data manipulation but nothing to heavy. Can HTML5 actually do this standalone? or is it still pretty much just the UI front-end?

### 2. HTML5 Applications - are they actually applications?

This is one that seems to give us the most confusion, different sources say different things on this subject, is HTML5 able of producing an actual application? or is it still just a website with an "app like" UI, much like what is achieved currently with JavaScript.

Comment: When using HTML 5, your functionality typically comes from JavaScript. Don't confuse this with Windows Apps that can either use HTML 5 and JavaScript, or XAML and C#.

Comment: So, you don't even know what HTML is and yet you want to rewrite `years` of WPF into HTML just `because`? You're going to have a really hard time. HTML doesn't even support `data`. There's no such thing as XAML's `{Binding}`, and HTML by itself is practically useless without either a backend or a lot of javascript. Then there is the subject of where will you store your data, if there is any data to be stored.

Comment: While i disagree with your assessment of how much i know, and don't think there was need for the snide attitude of your post (unless i'm misreading that), You may notice that entire subject was one of my questions because people keep talking about HTML5 as something MORE than html without specifics (hence the question), there is constant mention of data storage with HTML5, and HTML5 applications. Perhaps you could post your reply as an answer rather than a comment? Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll answer the first point. HTML5 is just a markup language, it has nothing to do with getting data from database. If you want to create a dynamic html website, then you need to have some server engine to exchange data with UI. With ASP.NET server engine you can go different directions.

- Have just pure HTML pages inside ASP.NET project (e.g. MVC, WebForms), and use services (like Web API/ServiceStack) to provide data. Typically you would use jQuery to get/post data to server and back.
- Use ASP.NET MVC to create a html5 compliant page and exchange data with the server using controllers.
- Use ASP.NET WebForms type of project. Here you would create aspx pages, which would contain only html markup (no server controls). In order to pass data from server to the view, you can use hidden fields here.